# Spree remove billing address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

How would I remove billing (or shipping) address in Spree checkout routine? I'm using spree 1.3

Answer (score 7):

You can remove the *shipping* address by removing the delivery step from your `checkout_flow` definition by putting this code inside your application at `app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb`:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  checkout_flow do
    go_to_state :address
    go_to_state :payment, :if => lambda { |order| order.payment_required? }
    go_to_state :confirm, :if => lambda { |order| order.confirmation_required? }
    go_to_state :complete
    remove_transition :from => :delivery, :to => :confirm
  end
end
```

By not having the delivery step there, Spree won't ask for a delivery address or delivery information for an order.

Comment: I have already tried that, but I'm still getting validation errors (fields in delivery are required). Shipment fields has been removed from the address form thou.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate for this, if you are using spree-core

In your view/spree/checkout/edit file, there is a render statement which involves error_messages.html.erb
= render :partial => 'spree/shared/error_messages', :locals => { :target => @order }

So now, you have to remove "ship" name from _error_messages.html.erb, then It will not show this kind of error.

Make some following changes in your spree/shared/_error_message file:

-target.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| 
    -unless (msg.include?("Ship")) 
        = msg 
Remember, make changes also in error count accordingly using loop here.
Currently I have no use of it, so made it comment

//= t(:errors_prohibited_this_record_from_being_saved, :count => target.errors.count)

---

I have also made comment on same question on github and stackoverflow-
https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/2571#issuecomment-13769093

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891781/how-to-remove-the-shipping-address-validation-in-spree-checkout-process/14957973#comment20997203_14957973